# How to remove an item from an observableArray with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The goal

Remove an item from an observableArray using KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I do not know — nothing happens.

My markup:

```
<button data-bind="click: Summary.remove">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</button>
```

My remove action:

```
self.remove = function (item) {
    self.products.remove(item);
};
```

My observableArray:

```
self.products = ko.observableArray();
```

### What is happening?

Nothing. The `self.remove` function is triggering but nothing happens to the item.

### More details?

I think that the details I've passed is enough, but if you need more, just let me know.

Comment: There isn't enough information here.  Please post a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue and I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming you are calling from inside a foreach binding, i believe you should be using the $parent context to call the remove function:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</button>
```

heres a sample fiddle for how I generally structure adding/removing items from a list:

http://jsfiddle.net/E53tc/

**html**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products"> 
    <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add New </button>
```

**javscript**

```
var product = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(data);
}

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.remove = function (item) {
        self.products.remove(item);
    };

    self.add = function () {
       self.products.push(new product("new product"));   
    }

    self.products = ko.observableArray();
}

var viewModel = new vm();
viewModel.products([ new product("product a"), new product("product b")]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a foreach binding, but in my application there is multiple ViewModels and I call for them by their names like: "Summary".remove; "Product".remove; "Person".remove; and I think it is not possible to use `$parent` with these names because I already tried and always with no success — `$parent` is undefined.

Comment: $parent is a helper that knockout provides so you can access the parent context inside `foreach`  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html    can you provide some more of your viewmodel structure and html markup to help identify the issue?

Comment: Kevin, was my bad. I forgot that I do not need to use `Summary.something` when I'm within a foreach loop. Your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much!